# viewDidLoad, awakeFromNib, initWithCoder:...Where to init members?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios

Just a simple question...I'm using Interface Builder for creating my view, and I wonder where I should initialize my UIViewController's member variables (which are not IBOutlets)...viewDidLoad? awakeFromNib? initWithCoder:?

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `awakeFromNib` if you need to do anything extra with your IB outlets before the view is actually loaded (so at the time post when the NIB is loaded), otherwise you can normally initialise member variables in `viewDidLoad`:

> This method is most commonly used to perform additional initialization steps on views that are loaded from nib files.

In general, if you follow how Apple's samples initialise member variables you'll be fine; you only need to consider changing the location of member initialisation if it's not appropriate to do it when the view is loaded.